# Using Object.keys returns integer array

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays

I am using iOS Workflow to pass the following string `{"person":"me","age":"30"}`to iOS Drafts using Run Drafts Action.

The action executes this Javascript

```
var txt = draft.content;

// var jsontest = {"person":"me" ,"age":"30"};

jsontest = txt.match(/{.*}/);

var str = JSON.parse(jsontest)

var list = JSON.stringify(str)

// List is {"person":"me" ,"age":"30"};

keylist = Object.keys(list);

keylist = keylist.join("|");  

alert(keylist);

// draft.defineTag('buttons',str);
```

The result should by person|age but it is `1|2|3|4|…` for the length of the string

What am I doing wrong.?

Comment: string keys are integers

Comment: If Statically define the string

Comment: If I statically define the string in the code the keys returned are person and me

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is unnecessary. You're ending up with a *string* of the content between the braces, and asking for its *keys*, which will be the indices of the string.

If you wanted the keys from the parsed object, then parse it (don't stringify it back to JSON), and use `Object.keys` on that.

```js
var jsontest = '{"person":"me" ,"age":"30"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsontest);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

console.log(keys.join("|"));
```

Comment: This works when the string is statically defined in the code as you have done. I am sending the string from one app to another. If I remove the JSON.stringify function I get a syntax error Type Error null is not an object (evaluating Object.keys(obj)

Comment: @user8960345: I can only respond to the information you've provided. I'm assuming you're getting some JSON data from somewhere, and need to parse it and get the keys. This will do that. If you're getting `null` from `JSON.parse`, then that's your data, and the problem has nothing to do with fetching keys.

Comment: It is assuredly my data but the data I see in the alert just before I call the object.keys method looks exactly like the string I included (and that you used in your example. The question is perhaps what might cause a string to be interpreted as a list of individual. characters as opposed to key-value pairs? They look identical.

Comment: Your solution works. But it throws a Type error during syntax check.  Because I normally program in ABAP I see distinctions between warning and fatal errors in the syntax check. I thought this was fatal. It is not. Thank you.